# Default line width in a `TikZ` diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

The diagram that I am providing depicts a pile of bricks. I have the border and brick the color of `BurntOrange`. I would like the border to be three times the default line width of the `\draw` command. Is the default line width `0.4pt`?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\noindent \begin{minipage}{4.5in}
\noindent \raggedright{\textbf{5.) }The following figure depicts a stack of bricks. A bricklayer \\
intends to number every brick that is not in the bottom \\
row with the sum of the numbers on the two bricks \\
supporting it. What is the number that will be \\
put on the top brick?}
\end{minipage}
%
\hspace{-0.5cm}
%
\raisebox{0mm}[0mm][0mm]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.west)]


%A pile of bricks is drawn.
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (0,0) -- (0.75,0) -- (0.75,0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- cycle;
%\node at (0.375,0.25){18};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (0.75,0) -- (1.5,0) -- (1.5,0.5) -- (0.75,0.5) -- cycle;
\node at (1.125,0.25){7};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (1.5,0) -- (2.25,0) -- (2.25,0.5) -- (1.5,0.5) -- cycle;
%\node at (1.875,0.25){15};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (2.25,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,0.5) -- (2.25,0.5) -- cycle;
%\node at (2.625,0.25){17};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (3,0) -- (3.75,0) -- (3.75,0.5) -- (3,0.5) -- cycle;
\node at (3.375,0.25){3};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (0.375,0.5) -- (1.125,0.5) -- (1.125,1) -- (0.375,1) -- cycle;
\node at (0.75,0.75){25};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (1.125,0.5) -- (1.875,0.5) -- (1.875,1) -- (1.125,1) -- cycle;
%\node at (1.5,0.75){22};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (1.875,0.5) -- (2.625,0.5) -- (2.625,1) -- (1.875,1) -- cycle;
\node at (2.25,0.75){32};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (2.625,0.5) -- (3.375,0.5) -- (3.375,1) -- (2.625,1) -- cycle;
%\node at (3,0.75){20};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (0.75,1) -- (1.5,1) -- (1.5,1.5) -- (0.75,1.5) -- cycle;
%\node at (1.125,1.25){47};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (1.5,1) -- (2.25,1) -- (2.25,1.5) -- (1.5,1.5) -- cycle;
\node at (1.875,1.25){54};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (2.25,1) -- (3,1) -- (3,1.5) -- (2.25,1.5) -- cycle;
%\node at (2.625,1.25){52};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (1.125,1.5) -- (1.875,1.5) -- (1.875,2) -- (1.125,2) -- cycle;
%\node at (1.5,1.75){101};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (1.875,1.5) -- (2.625,1.5) -- (2.625,2) -- (1.875,2) -- cycle;
%\node at (2.25,1.75){106};
\draw[draw=BurntOrange, line width=1.2pt, fill=BurntOrange!75] (1.5,2) -- (2.25,2) -- (2.25,2.5) -- (1.5,2.5) -- cycle;
%\node at (1.875,2.25){207};


\end{tikzpicture}
}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. According to the [Tik*Z*/PGF Manual](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=174) (section 15.3.1 *Graphic Parameters: Line Width, Line Cap, and Line Join*, on page 174), the default line width is 0.4 pt.

Other default options are:

- ultra thin:  0.1 pt
- very thin: 0.2 pt
- thin (default): 0.4 pt
- semithick: 0.6 pt
- thick: 0.8 pt
- very thick: 1.2 pt
- ultra thick: 1.6 pt

Comment: Sorry, I should have known that this question has been asked and answered somewhere else before! However, the linked answers do not refer to the manual … so, maybe my answer is still of some help to the OP.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate the citations.